# Finding node order in XML document in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

How can I find the order of nodes in an XML document?

What I have is a document like this:

```
<value code="1">
    <value code="11">
        <value code="111"/>
    </value>
    <value code="12">
        <value code="121">
            <value code="1211"/>
            <value code="1212"/>
        </value>
    </value>
</value>
```

and I'm trying to get this thing into a table defined like

```
CREATE TABLE values(
    code int,
    parent_code int,
    ord int
)
```

Preserving the order of the values from the XML document (they can't be ordered by their code). I want to be able to say

```
SELECT code 
FROM values 
WHERE parent_code = 121 
ORDER BY ord
```

and the results should, deterministically, be

```
code
1211
1212
```

I have tried

```
SELECT 
    value.value('@code', 'varchar(20)') code, 
    value.value('../@code', 'varchar(20)') parent, 
    value.value('position()', 'int')
FROM @xml.nodes('/root//value') n(value)
ORDER BY code desc
```

But it doesn't accept the `position()` function ('`position()`' can only be used within a predicate or XPath selector).

I guess it's possible some way, but how?

Comment: Do you have finite depth of nodes? If not, it's going to be a pain. And to confirm: you can not rely on codes?

Comment: ...and what output do you want from the xml?

Comment: I updated the question to provide more information. And no, there is an infinite depth.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can emulate the `position()` function by counting the number of sibling nodes preceding each node:

```sql
SELECT
    code = value.value('@code', 'int'),
    parent_code = value.value('../@code', 'int'),
    ord = value.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int')
FROM @Xml.nodes('//value') AS T(value)
```

Here is the result set:

```sql
code   parent_code  ord
----   -----------  ---
1      NULL         1
11     1            1
111    11           1
12     1            2
121    12           1
1211   121          1
1212   121          2
```

**How it works:**

- The [`for $i in .`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190945.aspx) clause defines a variable named `$i` that contains the current node (`.`). This is basically a hack to work around XQuery's lack of an XSLT-like `current()` function.
- The `../*` expression selects all siblings (children of the parent) of the current node.
- The `[. << $i]` predicate filters the list of siblings to those that precede ([`<<`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190935.aspx)) the current node (`$i`).
- We `count()` the number of preceding siblings and then add 1 to get the position. That way the first node (which has no preceding siblings) is assigned a position of 1.

Comment: I used this code on a rather large XML file and because the `for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1` part traverses all "sibling" nodes preceding every node this took forever (we let it run at work while going home, it had crashed the next day). So be forewarned that this code has an O(n^2) efficiency.

Answer (score 7):

SQL Server's `row_number()` actually accepts an xml-nodes column to order by. Combined with a [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) you can do this:

```
declare @Xml xml = 
'<value code="1">
    <value code="11">
        <value code="111"/>
    </value>
    <value code="12">
        <value code="121">
            <value code="1211"/>
            <value code="1212"/>
        </value>
    </value>
</value>'

;with recur as (
    select
        ordr        = row_number() over(order by x.ml),
        parent_code = cast('' as varchar(255)),
        code        = x.ml.value('@code', 'varchar(255)'),
        children    = x.ml.query('./value')
    from @Xml.nodes('value') x(ml)
    union all
    select
        ordr        = row_number() over(order by x.ml),
        parent_code = recur.code,
        code        = x.ml.value('@code', 'varchar(255)'),
        children    = x.ml.query('./value')
    from recur
    cross apply recur.children.nodes('value') x(ml)
)
select *
from recur
where parent_code = '121'
order by ordr
```

*As an aside, you can do this and it'll do what do you expect:*

```
select x.ml.query('.')
from @Xml.nodes('value/value')x(ml)
order by row_number() over (order by x.ml)
```

Why, if this works, you can't just `order by x.ml` directly without `row_number() over` is beyond me.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the position of the xml returned by a `x.nodes()` function like so:

```
row_number() over (order by (select 0))
```

For example:

```
DECLARE @x XML
SET @x = '<a><b><c>abc1</c><c>def1</c></b><b><c>abc2</c><c>def2</c></b></a>'

SELECT
    b.query('.'),
    row_number() over (partition by 0 order by (select 0))
FROM
    @x.nodes('/a/b') x(b)
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that the order will match what is desired

Answer (score 3):

[The answer by erikkallen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1134075/521799) is absolutely correct.

However, if the original document/schema may be modified, an alternative is to store the position/index in an attribute. I use a mix of both approaches, depending who the "originator" of the XML is and the type of queries that need to be performed upon it. At the end of the day I rue most use of XML except possibly "dumb storage" in SQL Server and am usually happy when I can dump it (XML) for normalized tables.

Happy dealing with the unmentioned limitations of "enterprise-grade" products -- the wonders never end.

Comment: +1 for your "rue most use of XML".  It really sucks when you have to select nodes much less update them.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/wishlist.html) document and this [connect entry](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=383888) it is not possible, but the Connect entry contains two workarounds.

I do it like this:

```
WITH n(i) AS (SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9),
     o(i) AS (SELECT n3.i * 100 + n2.i * 10 + n1.i FROM n n1, n n2, n n3)
SELECT v.value('@code', 'varchar(20)') AS code,
       v.value('../@code', 'varchar(20)') AS parent,
       o.i AS ord
  FROM o
 CROSS APPLY @xml.nodes('/root//value[sql:column("o.i")]') x(v)
 ORDER BY o.i
```

Comment: Every-time I try to see if there is a good way to perform this I always feel like crying. It's the only way I have found (actually, I use a numbers table, but same ugly hack) -- it's an absolutely pathetic excuse for a server which "supports XML" and makes simple shredding and access much more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

I see answer by @Ben and... get new sollution

```
 row_number() over (order by (select null))
```

as

```
  SELECT value.value('@code', 'varchar(20)') code, 
  value.value('../@code', 'varchar(20)') parent, 
  row_number() over (order by (select null))
  FROM @xml.nodes('/root//value') n(value)
```