# SQL to Convert XML to table

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, t-sql, xpath, xquery

In SQL 2005, is there a way to convert the following xml into a table?

```
<root>
  <r>
    <data>"col1"</data>
    <data>"col2"</data>
    <data>"col3"</data>
  </r>
  <r>
    <data>"data1"</data>
    <data>""</data>
    <data>"data3"</data>
  </r>
  <r>
    <data>"data"</data>
    <data>"data"</data>
    <data>"data"</data>
  </r>
</root>
```

I want the output to be

```
col1 col2 col3
----------------
data      data3
data data data
```

The xml can have different number of columns so the solution needs to account for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = 
'<root>
  <r>
    <data>"col1"</data>
    <data>"col2"</data>
    <data>"col3"</data>
  </r>
  <r>
    <data>"data1"</data>
    <data>""</data>
    <data>"data3"</data>
  </r>
  <r>
    <data>"data"</data>
    <data>"data"</data>
    <data>"data"</data>
  </r>
</root>'

declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
set @SQL = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + ',replace(r.r.value(''data['+
         cast(T.rn as nvarchar(10))+
         ']'', ''varchar(10)''), ''"'','''') as '+
         quotename(replace(T.ColName, '"', '')) 
from
(
  select
    r.r.value('.', 'sysname') as ColName,
    row_number() over(order by (select 1)) as rn
  from @xml.nodes('/root/r[1]/data') r(r)
) as T

set @SQL = 'select '+stuff(@SQL, 1, 1, '')+
        ' from @x.nodes(''/root/r[position()>1]'') r(r)'

exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@x xml', @x = @xml
```

Since I use dynamic SQL here it is appropriate to suggest reading [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#sp_executesql).

An explanation of what is going on.

This query is used to get the columns names from the first `r` node:

```
select
    r.r.value('.', 'varchar(10)') as ColName,
    row_number() over(order by (select 1)) as rn
  from @xml.nodes('/root/r[1]/data') r(r)
```

`/root/r[1]` makes sure we get the first row. `row_number()` enumerates the columns making a connection between a number and the column name.

The resulting query in @SQL is this:

```
select 
  replace(r.r.value('data[1]', 'varchar(10)'), '"','') as [col1],
  replace(r.r.value('data[2]', 'varchar(10)'), '"','') as [col2],
  replace(r.r.value('data[3]', 'varchar(10)'), '"','') as [col3] 
from @xml.nodes('/root/r[position()>1]') r(r)
```

`/root/r[position()>1]` gets all `r` nodes except the first one. The `1` in `data[1]` comes from `row_number()` and `[col1]` comes from the corresponding column name. `quotename()` adds the brackets `[]` to the column alias. Without `quotename()` this query could be used for SQL injection. `replace()` is used to remove `"` from the string. It will remove all occurrences of `"` so if you expect `"` to be part of a value you could use `substring()` to remove `"` instead.

I have used `varchar(10)` as the size of column data. You should modify that to whatever you need.

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic and exactly what I need. Thanks @Mikael Eriksson for the explanations too.

Answer (score 2):

Not with a varying number of columns: SQL in general is fixed column

However, you can anticipate this somewhat

```
DECLARE @foo AS xml = '<root>
  <r>
    <data>"col1"</data>
    <data>"col2"</data>
    <data>"col3"</data>
  </r>
  <r>
    <data>"data1"</data>
    <data>""</data>
    <data>"data3"</data>
  </r>
  <r>
    <data>"data"</data>
    <data>"data"</data>
    <data>"data"</data>
  </r>
</root>'

SELECT
   REPLACE(x.item.value('(data)[1]', 'varchar(100)'), '"', '') AS col1,
   REPLACE(x.item.value('(data)[2]', 'varchar(100)'), '"', '') AS col2,
   REPLACE(x.item.value('(data)[3]', 'varchar(100)'), '"', '') AS col3,
   REPLACE(x.item.value('(data)[4]', 'varchar(100)'), '"', '') AS col4,
   REPLACE(x.item.value('(data)[5]', 'varchar(100)'), '"', '') AS col5,
   REPLACE(x.item.value('(data)[6]', 'varchar(100)'), '"', '') AS col6,
   REPLACE(x.item.value('(data)[7]', 'varchar(100)'), '"', '') AS col7,
   REPLACE(x.item.value('(data)[8]', 'varchar(100)'), '"', '') AS col8,
   REPLACE(x.item.value('(data)[9]', 'varchar(100)'), '"', '') AS col9,
   REPLACE(x.item.value('(data)[10]', 'varchar(100)'), '"', '') AS col10
FROM
   @foo.nodes('/root/r') x(item)
```

There is also no guarantee of node order evaluation by default which complicates extracting the first row column names.

Based on this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/q/1134075/27535, you can use this SQL to identify row 1

```
;WITH n(i) AS (SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9),
     o(i) AS (SELECT n3.i * 100 + n2.i * 10 + n1.i FROM n n1, n n2, n n3)
SELECT
   REPLACE(x.item.value('(data)[1]', 'varchar(100)'), '"', '') AS col1,
   REPLACE(x.item.value('(data)[2]', 'varchar(100)'), '"', '') AS col2,
   REPLACE(x.item.value('(data)[3]', 'varchar(100)'), '"', '') AS col3,
   REPLACE(x.item.value('(data)[4]', 'varchar(100)'), '"', '') AS col4,
   REPLACE(x.item.value('(data)[5]', 'varchar(100)'), '"', '') AS col5,
   REPLACE(x.item.value('(data)[6]', 'varchar(100)'), '"', '') AS col6,
   REPLACE(x.item.value('(data)[7]', 'varchar(100)'), '"', '') AS col7,
   REPLACE(x.item.value('(data)[8]', 'varchar(100)'), '"', '') AS col8,
   REPLACE(x.item.value('(data)[9]', 'varchar(100)'), '"', '') AS col9,
   REPLACE(x.item.value('(data)[10]', 'varchar(100)'), '"', '') AS col10,
   o.i
FROM
   o
   CROSS APPLY
   @foo.nodes('/root/r[sql:column("o.i")]') x(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it, but I know it can be done...

Take a look at this tutorial, it seems to be pretty close to exactly what you're asking for.
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/06/18/60235.aspx

Comment: Thanks @AllenG, but my data has already been imported into a table as a nvarchar(Max), from what I gather BULK is best for importing large XML files from the file system.