# In SQL Server 2005, how can I store XML nodes in a table while preserving document order?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-openxml

I have an xml file where the ordering of nodes is important, like this one:

```
<Queue>
  <User name="Bob"/>
  <User name="Jane"/>
  <User name="Douglas"/>
  <User name="Samantha"/>
</Queue>
```

I'm using OPENXML to store these nodes in a table variable. How can I ensure that the node order is preserved when I insert into the table variable?

Note, I'm using OPENXML and not xquery so this is not a duplicate of: [Finding node order in XML document in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134075/finding-node-order-in-xml-document-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently doing the following, relying on the 'mp:id' to provide the ordering.

```
DECLARE @xmltext NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @xmltext = 
N'
<Queue>
  <User name="Bob"/>
  <User name="Jane"/>
  <User name="Douglas"/>
  <User name="Samantha"/>
</Queue>';

DECLARE @xmlObjectHandler INT;
    -- Set up XML and the appropriate namespace(s) we'll be using
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @xmlObjectHandler OUTPUT, @xmltext;

DECLARE @TUserQueue TABLE (
    Ordinal INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    UserName NVARCHAR(200)
)

INSERT INTO @TUserQueue
SELECT 
    UserName
FROM
    OPENXML(@xmlObjectHandler, '/Queue/User')   
    WITH (
        NodeId INT '@mp:id',
        UserName NVARCHAR(200) '@name'
    ) AS users
ORDER BY users.NodeId;

SELECT * FROM @TUserQueue
```