# Parse XML where data is pivoted

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing, xquery, xquery-sql

I have the following XML data

```
<browse result="1">
  <th>
    <td label="Company ID"></td>
    <td label="Company Name"></td>
    <td label="Country"></td>
    <td label="Region"></td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC01</td>
    <td>Company 1</td>
    <td>United States</td>
    <td>North America</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC02</td>
    <td>Company 2</td>
    <td>China</td>
    <td>Asia</td>
  </tr>
</browse>
```

my final table should look like this

| Company ID | Company Name | Country | Region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC01 | Company 1 | United States | North America |
| ABC02 | Company 2 | China | Asia |

or its pivoted version

| label | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Company ID | ABC01 | ABC02 |
| Company Name | Company 1 | Company 2 |
| Country | United States | China |
| Region | North America | Asia |

This is what I have tried so far

```
declare @xmldata nvarchar(4000) = '<browse result="1">
  <th>
    <td label="Company ID"></td>
    <td label="Company Name"></td>
    <td label="Country"></td>
    <td label="Region"></td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC01</td>
    <td>Company 1</td>
    <td>United States</td>
    <td>North America</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC02</td>
    <td>Company 2</td>
    <td>China</td>
    <td>Asia</td>
  </tr>
</browse>'

select
     a.value('@label', 'varchar(max)') as label
    ,b.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as value
from (select top (1) CAST(REPLACE(CAST(@xmldata AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'utf-8','utf-16') AS XML) as xmldata) as s
    outer apply s.xmldata.nodes('/browse/th/td') as l(a)
    outer apply s.xmldata.nodes('/browse/tr/td') as v(b)
```

but it gives me 32 rows, and most of them is wrongly duplicated combinations of the 4 labels with the values. How should I accomplish this?

Comment: Are the column/label names fixed or are they dynamic? Can they change order?

Comment: hi! they are fixed. what is stated in the labels is fixed throughout the whole file

Comment: If they are not fixed you can use some XQuery voodoo to get the position, and then refer back to it in a predicate https://dbfiddle.uk/-jo-Loni

Comment: That really is some voodoo magic there, @Charlieface . Based on the fiddle's name, can we call the "Jo Loni technique"? :)

Comment: @ThomA It's an old trick, I used it a few times `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A14868997+let+return+count+%5Bsql*%5D` I don't remember where I got it. Also here is the oldest mention I can find of it https://stackoverflow.com/a/9863151/14868997 might have got it from there

Comment: @ThomA Basically you put the node you want in an XQuery variable `$i` then you count through all its sibling nodes that are before it, and add 1. It's really slow by the way, on big files it's often better to just use the more unreliable `row_number`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If* we can assume that the values are in static positions then you only need to look at the `tr` nodes, and then get each `td` node from that using their ordinal positions:

```sql
DECLARE @xml xml = '<browse result="1">
  <th>
    <td label="Company ID"></td>
    <td label="Company Name"></td>
    <td label="Country"></td>
    <td label="Region"></td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC01</td>
    <td>Company 1</td>
    <td>United States</td>
    <td>North America</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC02</td>
    <td>Company 2</td>
    <td>China</td>
    <td>Asia</td>
  </tr>
</browse>';

SELECT b.th.value('(td/text())[1]','varchar(20)') AS CompanyID,
       b.th.value('(td/text())[2]','varchar(20)') AS CompanyName,
       b.th.value('(td/text())[3]','varchar(20)') AS Country,
       b.th.value('(td/text())[4]','varchar(20)') AS Region
FROM @xml.nodes('browse/tr') b(th);
```

You'll likely need to adjust the data types, but I very much doubt that `varchar(MAX)` is appropriate; if you are using IDs that are *over* **8,000** characters long then you have a problem.

Comment: may i ask what should be added if some of the td nodes are null? for example <td>ABC03</td><td /> <td /> <td>Asia</td>. in this case, "Asia" would go directly to the Company Name instead of staying in Region.

Comment: Change to `(td[1]/text())[1]`, `(td[2]/text())[1]`, etc, @xE99 .